# sql profiler filters: stored procedure where parameter value = X

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I want to profile a stored procedure but only when the input parameter is equal to a specific value. I'm currently doing an RPC: Starting with a filter on ObjectName for the stored procedure which works but I added a filter on TextData for the value I'm looking for and nothing is coming through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use %% in your value like you would a normal query.